# mysql query optimization with join and subquery

Tags: php, mysql, join

Can someone pls help with this. From the slow log This query below takes 11 seconds to run and its eating up server resources. How do i re-write this query to achieve greater optimization?

P.S: The tables are indexed.

The query :

```
SELECT SUM(the_val) AS value
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT basic_data.id,
                   att2.the_val
   FROM province_create
   INNER JOIN basic_data ON province_create.province = basic_data.province
   INNER JOIN att2 ON att2.church_id = basic_data.id
   WHERE province_create.block = 0
     AND att2.month = 'Feb'
     AND att2.year = '2017'
     AND basic_data.parish = 1
     AND att2.report = 'ATTENDANCE'
     AND province_create.disable = 0 ) t1;
```

The EXPLAIN report:

[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => PRIMARY
            [select_type] => PRIMARY
            [2] => 
            [table] => 
            [3] => ALL
            [type] => ALL
            [4] => 
            [possible_keys] => 
            [5] => 
            [key] => 
            [6] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [7] => 
            [ref] => 
            [8] => 38339
            [rows] => 38339
            [9] => 
            [Extra] => 
        )

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [id] => 2
        [1] => DERIVED
        [select_type] => DERIVED
        [2] => province_create
        [table] => province_create
        [3] => ALL
        [type] => ALL
        [4] => kk,province,kkk
        [possible_keys] => kk,province,kkk
        [5] => 
        [key] => 
        [6] => 
        [key_len] => 
        [7] => 
        [ref] => 
        [8] => 261
        [rows] => 261
        [9] => Using where; Using temporary
        [Extra] => Using where; Using temporary
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [id] => 2
        [1] => DERIVED
        [select_type] => DERIVED
        [2] => basic_data
        [table] => basic_data
        [3] => ref
        [type] => ref
        [4] => PRIMARY,kk,kkk,k,parish
        [possible_keys] => PRIMARY,kk,kkk,k,parish
        [5] => kk
        [key] => kk
        [6] => 56
        [key_len] => 56
        [7] => databaseuser.province_create.province
        [ref] => databaseuser.province_create.province
        [8] => 39
        [rows] => 39
        [9] => Using index; Distinct
        [Extra] => Using index; Distinct
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [id] => 2
        [1] => DERIVED
        [select_type] => DERIVED
        [2] => att2
        [table] => att2
        [3] => ref
        [type] => ref
        [4] => indpull,mmm
        [possible_keys] => indpull,mmm
        [5] => mmm
        [key] => mmm
        [6] => 57
        [key_len] => 57
        [7] => databaseuser.basic_data.id
        [ref] => databaseuser.basic_data.id
        [8] => 1
        [rows] => 1
        [9] => Using where; Distinct
        [Extra] => Using where; Distinct
    )
```

)

Comment: (a) How many records are involved? (b) Would it make a difference if you didn’t include `basic_data.id` in your subquery?

Comment: Please show a sample of the original data.  Why is `SELECT DISTINCT` needed?

Comment: @Manngo. (a) The province_create table - about 300 records. The b

Comment: @uzor Is `basic_data.id` a primary key? There’s usually not much point in including a primary key in a `SELECT DISTINCT` clause, as it’s already distinct. Also, did you really want `att2.the_val` to be distinct? I have no idea what the value means, but you’re excluding multiple occurrences of the value. In other words, why are they distinct?

Comment: @Manngo (a) The province_create table - about 300 records, the basic_data table about 50,000 records, the att2 table almost 2 million records. (B) The select distinct basic_data.id is needed because some ids on the att2 table appeared more than once. when i took it out it gave me a different (false) result

Comment: @Manngo yes the id is a primary key on the basic_data table but it is not unique on the att2 table. I placed distinct there because i did not want it to multiple sum for the same id.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me assume that `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed.  Then the query can be written as:

```
SELECT SUM(a.the_val)
FROM province_create pc INNER JOIN
     basic_data bd
     ON pc.province = bd.province INNER JOIN
     att2 a
     ON a.church_id = bd.id
WHERE pc.block = 0 AND
      a.month = 'Feb' AND
      a.year = '2017' AND
      bd.parish = 1 AND
      a.report = 'ATTENDANCE'
      pc.disable = 0 ;
```

Second, you should try indexes on the tables.  It is hard to tell what the best index would be, so try adding the following:

- `attr2(year, month, report, church_id, the_val)`
- `basic_data(id, province, parish)`
- `province_create(province, disable)`

This index should help even if the `SELECT DISTINCT` is needed.  However, you need to understand why you are getting duplicates and fix the root cause of that problem for best performance.

Comment: Thanks it enhanced performance significantly. However the issue is that on the att2 table the church_id (which is a foreign key of basic_data.id) is not unique. (i.e there are times where a paricular church_id,month,year, report appears more than once). The value of what i am getting from your solution is higher than what it should be. so how can i (a) make sure that is does not double sum or (b) is there a way can i search for values on the att2 table that are duplicates (based on basic_data.id) and delete them? Thanks. your help is appreciated

Comment: @uzor . . . Does the index work on your original query?

Comment: yes it worked on the original query but worked better with your solution. right now am i researching ways of deleting duplicate entries in a mysql table so that i can adopt your solution.